# Preview, can it be used to cut off pages?

Tags: pdf, preview

In some academic conferences, Preview is not allowed to cut off pages. For example: https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2021/Styles/example_paper.pdf

[image]

```
Please do not use Apple’s preview to cut off supplementary material. In previous years it has altered margins, and created headaches at the camera-ready stage.
```

Now, is this will cause an issue?

Thank you.